# vb.net: setting focus on nested custom controls

Tags: vb.net

I have a nested custom control that I need to set focus on. I have it all internally wired up to automatically set the focus when the form loads, but when it comes up on screen, the designated accept button for the parent form is in focus instead. Even when is disassociate the accept button it still does not set correctly. How can I ensure my desired control gets focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is that you would like to make a textbox (or button, etc) on a user control have focus when the form loads.  Try setting the ActiveControl of the user control to the textbox (or which ever control) and then calling focus on it.  For example:

```
Private Sub myUserControl_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   ActiveControl = myTextbox
   myTextbox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the tab order. If your custom control is on the same level as buttons (has the same parent), make sure your control and any containter it is in has tab index 0.